# Angular 2 404 error when attempting login

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have an angular 2 application which talks to a standalone backend nodejs api. Out of know where I am getting a 404 when I try to log in to my application. This just started happening and I went back to different versions of code in both front and backend to see if something in the recent code broke my app. I have verified the node backend is running by checking its existence in the activity monitor. There is absolutely no activity in the console for the backend when I try to hit the endpoint.

When I look at the network tab I am getting a 404 but the rest of the details seem to indicate that everything was sent as expected including the correct request url and request payload.

The only thing that I am not sure is normal is there seems to be two login attempts with the first one resulting in a 204. I actually do not know if this is a normal behavior.

After attempting to login I get the follow report in the network tab:

[image]

The details for both listings are below:

[image]

[image]

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Been wasting lots of precious time fighting with this. Thanks.

Update with some backend code per request:

The entry file is large but basically works like this:

***Services and Models are instantiated and passed into the routes:***

```
let authRouter = authCreateRouter(passport, services);
```

***Auth Router:***

```
module.exports = (passport, services) => {
  let router = express.Router();

  router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
          passport.authenticate('login', (err, user, info) => {
              if (err) {
                  logger.info({
                      err,
                      stack: err.stack
                  }, 'the error');
                  return next(err);
              }
              if (!user) {
                  logger.info({
                      user
                  }, 'this user could not be authenticated');
                  return res.status(401).json({
                      success: false
                  });
              }
              let token = jwt.sign({
                  id: user.id
              }, process.env.SESSION_SECRET, {
                  expiresIn: '12h'
              });
              res.json({
                  success: true,
                  userId: user.id,
                  signup: user.signup,
                  avatarUrl: user.avatarUrl,
                  accountVerified: user.accountVerified,
                  user,
                  token
              });

          })(req, res, next);

      });
};
```

The above code then interacts with the appropriate service. The thing is none of this code has changed so it is not likely the issue.

Comment: Can you share the server side (node) code?

Comment: One thing that looks odd to me, but could be part of your setup. Why is the port number of the /auth/login different to the port number of the website/referrer?

Comment: Yes I noticed that. I am not sure. Im about to update my post with some backend code. Just not sure what is needed.

Comment: @Aaron please share all the relevant code. Where does "/auth" come from. Where do you bootstrap nodejs? What is the port?

Comment: I apologize for the lack of code. This is a really big app and there is a lot of code. I found the problem. The developers on the backend failed to add proper error handling and the backend was not starting up properly. Evidently there was some values that were deleted from another database that were not found and the app was not handling that gracefully. The app appeared to be running and when I was checking in the activity monitor it was showing up as if it was running.